# How to find duplicates only in rows with a specific value & use conditional formatting to fill those duplicate cells

Tags: google-sheets

I'm working on a data reduction project for a game mod. As part of that project, I've gathered a bunch of info regarding the structures & units in the mod to help determine what data is redundant & can be changed or deleted. The problem I'm currently unable to get past is that while I can find all the duplicates in a column (filled with cyan), I need to be able to find only duplicates in rows that have "Units" in the Mod column & then use conditional formatting to fill only those duplicate cells (green).

| Mod | Description |
| --- | --- |
| Units | Heavy Artillery Installation |
| Units | Heavy Artillery Installation |
| BrewLAN for LOUD | Heavy Assault Bot |
| Units | Heavy Assault Bot |
| BlackOps Unleashed | Heavy Attack Drone |
| Wyvern | Heavy Gatling Bot |
| BrewLAN for LOUD | Heavy Gunship |
| Total Mayhem | Heavy Gunship |
| Units | Heavy Gunship |
| BlackOps Unleashed | Heavy Hover Tank |
| Total Mayhem | Heavy Point Defense |
| Total Mayhem | Heavy Point Defense |
| Units | Heavy Point Defense |
| BrewLAN for LOUD | Heavy Shield Generator |
| Wyvern | Heavy Support Cruiser |
| Units | Heavy Tank |
| Units | Heavy Tank |
| Wyvern | Heavy Tank |
| BlackOps Unleashed | Helltank |

I've tried various combinations of COUNTIF, COUNTIFS, FILTER, QUERY, INDEX(MATCH) & ARRAYFORMULA formulas & have come close, but have yet to find exactly what I'm looking for. These are the formulas I'm currently using for conditional formatting:

Duplicates in rows with Units (Green):
`=(($A2="Units") * (COUNTIF($O$2:$O$851, $O2)>1))`

All duplicates:
`=COUNTIF($O$2:$O$851, $O2)>1`

[Partial dataset with examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOcDX.jpg)

In the image, you can see O446 & O447 are filled green because both of those are duplicates (Heavy Artillery Installation) & are both in rows with Units in the Mod column. The same can be said for O485 & O486 because both of those have duplicates of Heavy Tank & both have Units in the Mod column. You can also see that O487 is filled cyan because while it is a duplicate of Heavy Tank, it doesn't have Units in the Mod column. These are examples of what I'm expecting.

When it comes to O449, O457 & O474, those are being filled because they're duplicate values of the row(s) above or below them; unfortunately, they're being filled green when they should be filled cyan because they're duplicate values but don't have Units in the Mod column.

While I'm hoping that the solution to this can be a formula (with or without a helper column), I'm also willing to use Apps Script if that would be easier (or necessary).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try:*

***Apply to range***: `O:O`

***Custom formula is***: `=and($A1="Units",countif(index(A:A&O:O),$A1&$O1)>1)`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I don't misunderstand your requirements, you need for green to be duplicates with both values being with "Units". Then you can use COUNTIFS, checking also if it's Units

```
=(($A2="Units") * (COUNTIFS($O$2:$O$851, $O2,$A$2:$A$851,"Units")>1))
```

[image]